# Angular 4 - open pop up window

Tags: angular

If I do the below, it opens the window in a new tab

```
<a [routerLink]="['/name', 'param1']" target="_blank" >{{ name }}</a>
```

Instead of a new tab, I need to open the same route in a pop up window. Javascript code to open a pop up window looks like this

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=300,height=250');">test</a>
```

I am not able to make out how to fit in routerLink in this example. Is there another way to open pop up window when using angular?

Comment: why use routerlink? you're not changing routes, you're opening a new window

Comment: How would I open a new component in the pop up window and pass parameters to it, if I do not use routerLink?

Comment: try with ngx-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score -3):

By using angular material you can do it, i don't know how exactly it works in 4 but i think that from 5 and up it works perfect

import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';